# como fazer uma busca com vários filtros como parâmetro no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou com uma dúvida de como fazer uma busca de clientes com vários filtros.

Exemplo: `nome cliente`, `tipo de cliente`, `status do cliente`, `endereço`, `cidade`.

Detalhe: todos estes filtros estão em campos diferentes.

Como fazer isso usando o Eloquent do Laravel?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com Laravel, mas já tentou alguma coisa? Se sim, posta o código do que tentou. Já olhou na documentação http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent . E pelo que olhei, se é que entendi, seria algo como `$query->where('campo', $valor)->where('outroCampo', $outroValor)`

Comment: Coloque as tabela ou tabelas que componhoem esse Model, inclusive a classe do Model, por favor, dessa forma imaginando acredito que você não terá resposta nenhum ou até ter alguma que se aproxime mais da sua realidade ...

Comment: O que você quer dizer "estão em campos diferentes"? você quer fazer uma consulta baseada em filtros de formulários html? Se for, já tenho uma resposta prontinha :)

Answer (score 3):

Analisando a documentação, lá em http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres
tem esse exemplo que irá te atender muito bem:

```
MeuModel::where(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->orWhere('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

Ai você pode montar dinamicamente o que você quer, aninhando quantos "orWhere" você precisar.